# LINQ to SQL array list insertion

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

how insert data array to database with linq to sql?

```
 DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
    simpleTbl tbl = new simpleTbl();
    string[] str =File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/str.txt"));

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
       tbl.Name =str[i];
    }
  db.simpleTbl.InsertOnSubmit(tbl);
    db.SubmitChanges();
```

but dosent work

Comment: what is the 'sym' variable, maybe you should put the tbt variable on that place? And what error do you get?

Comment: all array value dosent inset to database

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: for example one record of 10 is insert

Comment: what doesn't work? the code looks incorrect. you are effectively just getting the last str[i] and assigning it to tbl.Name. makes no sense. so basically no matter how many iterations there are, it will only ever assign the last one to tbl.Name. you are then inserting the last value tbl.Name has

Comment: @ ahmed : how solved this problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
using(DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    string[] strings = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/str.txt"));

    foreach (var str in strings )
    {
        db.simpleTbl.InsertOnSubmit(new simpleTbl(){ Name = str });
    }

    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

You need to insert a new item for each entry in the string array.

Comment: if i have two array then how insert two array data in data base?

Answer (score 0):

this code is correct but uses for one array if i have more one array how implement this?

```
using(DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
```

{
    string[] strings = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/str.txt"));

```
foreach (var str in strings )
{
    db.simpleTbl.InsertOnSubmit(new simpleTbl(){ Name = str });
}

db.SubmitChanges();
```

}